# Placing an object randomly depending on window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to place an object on a random location depending on the window size.
`LayoutRoot` is the name of the grid it's placed in.

```
     //Give Dot a random position
     int left = random.Next(LayoutRoot.MinWidth, LayoutRoot.MaxWidth);
     int top = random.Next(-900, 900);
     Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
```

Error on LayoutRoot.MinWidth & MaxWidth: `Cannot convert double to int`

tried

```
    //Give Dot a random position
    double left = random.NextDouble(LayoutRoot.MinWidth, LayoutRoot.MaxWidth);
    double top = random.Next(-900, 900);
    Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
```

Error on NextDouble: `Method NextDouble takes 2 arguments`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `Grid`? I'd think you'd want to use a `Canvas` if you're trying to randomly place something on the screen. You'd use `Canvas.SetX(x); Canvas.SetY(y);`  The `Canvas` control is intended for this type of thing, while the `Grid` is intended for laying out in neat rows & columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok going to up this one up a bit. Modified your code. This code doesn't assume any predefined height or width, it gets that based on the current size of the `LayoutRoot`. It also offsets the `Dot` size so it doesn't fall off the screen.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" Fill="Black" x:Name="Dot"></Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Don't move dot until the window is loaded, not necessary but generally you don't want to hold up the window from displaying.
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            // The farthest left the dot can be
            double minLeft = 0;
            // The farthest right the dot can be without it going off the screen
            double maxLeft = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth - Dot.Width;
            // The farthest up the dot can be
            double minTop = 0;
            // The farthest down the dot can be without it going off the screen
            double maxTop = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight - Dot.Height;


            double left = RandomBetween(minLeft, maxLeft);
            double top = RandomBetween(minTop, maxTop);
            Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
        }

        private double RandomBetween(double min, double max)
        {
            return random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors but when i start the application the object is nowhere to be found?

Answer (score 0):

this might work.

```
double mWidth = LayoutRoot.MinWidth;
double mxWidth = LayoutRoot.MaxWidth;
double left = random.NextDouble(mWidth, mxWidth);
double top = random.Next(-900, 900);
Dot.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Got the error `Method NextDouble takes 2 arguments` again.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at the answer given by Kelly I had a similar issue where the object would not display after loading. My goal was to have the welcome screen of an application randomly move every 10 seconds. So following his design there was an issue where because the grid did not have an actual length due to the lack of column/row definitions we have to force the app to recalculate size at every attempt to randomize.

Here is the XAML I used:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="WelcomeTextBlock" 
               Height="200" 
               Style="{StaticResource WelcomeTextBlock}">
        Welcome!
    </TextBlock>
    <Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" x:Name="Dot"/>
</Grid>
```

And more importantly the actual code-behind:

```
public partial class WelcomePage : Page
    {
        private static Random Rnd = new Random();

        private static DispatcherTimer _timer;

        public WelcomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
            this.Unloaded += OnClosing;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Margin = GetNewMargin();
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)};
            _timer.Tick += MoveWelcome;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void MoveWelcome(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Margin = GetNewMargin();
        }

        private Thickness GetNewMargin()
        {
            this.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            this.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, this.DesiredSize.Width, this.DesiredSize.Height));
            var maxLeft = this.LayoutRoot.ActualWidth - Dot.Width;
            var maxTop = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight - Dot.Height;
            var left = RandomBetween(0, maxLeft);
            var top = RandomBetween(0, maxTop);
            return new Thickness(left, top, 0 ,0);
        }

        private static void OnClosing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        private static double RandomBetween(double min, double max) => Rnd.NextDouble() * (max - min) + max;
```

Besides the timer functionality the major change here is that when the margin thickness is being calculated we force the window, or in my case page to update the measurements of the screen and arrange the items correctly.